# How to modify the class from it's extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I'm trying to create two method to serialize/deserialize classes using `Json.Net` and save/load them to/from file and this is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace System
{
    public static class SystemExtentions
    {
        public static void SaveToFile(this object data, string FileName)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FileName))
            {
                string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                writer.Write(s);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void LoadFromFile<t>(t date,string FileName)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {

                data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<t>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in `LoadFromFile` method `data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<t>(reader.ReadToEnd());` doesn't work! it means that if I had this code:

```
Class1 c1=new Class1();
c1.LoadFromFile<Class1>("c1.clf");
```

after the code runs the properties of `c1` doesn't change.

**I want to Know why and is there any solution to modify the class or set it's properties(deserialize it!) from `LoadFromFile` in independent(independent to class type and properties)(dynamically) way?**

Comment: Please define "doesn't work"!

Comment: Please read your question and ask yourself if anyone not inside your head would understand it. What do you mean by "modify the class"? What do you want to achieve? What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Just a tip, it is a common naming convention to use uppercase 'T' as the generic parameter.

Comment: @jeroenh meant that we have no idea what "doesn't work" means for you. Errors? Exceptions? Wrong behaviour (if so, what exactly does that mean)? Something else?

Comment: @Oded Doesn't work means the when I call `class1.LoadFromFile<Class1>("file.txt");` the `class1` doesn't change!

Comment: It probably does - at least the _copy_ of it does (see what `data` is when breaking on `reader.Close()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your LoadFromFile method takes a parameter of type `t` that your are assigning to inside the method. This does not make sense. Instead, use a return value:

```
public static T LoadFromFile<T>(string fileName)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
    {
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(WpfApplication.Helper.Decrypt(reader.ReadToEnd()));
    }
}
```

This would allow you to use this code like this:

```
Class1 c1 = LoadFromFile<Class1>("c1.clf");
```

Side note: no need to explicitly close a streamreader if you use the `using` construct

Comment: I'm doing this way. But It need that to create an instance of class then Load it. I want to no create an instace of class!

Comment: Please provide more context, possibly some more code on how and why you are using this. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I have a lot of different classes that I need to save their data in file and load them. I'm looking for a solution to have just one method to serialize/deserialize classes and save/load them from files!

Comment: So why isn't this answer a solution?